# How to refresh in SPA (react, vue)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application

If the source code or function is changed in the SPA project, you must deploy it to the server again.

If the service is deployed, it will continue to load the cached js value unless refreshed. How do I fix this?

Comment: what server are you using. typically a server would rebuild the entire project after it detects changes so that shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: This is expected behaviour and until user will not refreshes his page, new changes will not be loaded

Comment: What exactly is your setup? This is already done in CRA and Vue CLI in a way that answers describe.

Comment: [@Hadi Pawar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7396313/hadi-pawar)
i use a nginx

Comment: [@Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask)
I am using CRA(create-react-app).

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I have documented the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099943/forcing-refresh-of-cached-js-in-spa-reactjs-that-changes-between-requests-usin Are you saying the user MUST refresh and this in the ONLY way?

Comment: @logixplayer Yes, if a page has a heading text `ABC` and user has open that page, now if you deploy new build with heading text `XYZ`, it will be reflect in user's open page/app unless user will reload that page. Even with lazy loading/code splitting, that chunk has been retrieved and will not be fetching on route change unless user refreshes the page/app. You can't push your change to all clients/apps opened in browsers. You should apply caching on all content except `index.html` so it will be fetched everytime and other content will be come from cache if index.html is referring to same  file

Comment: @logixplayer When new build will update chunks path name like `src="chunk.1d23s.js", if that is not cached by browser, browser will fetch it from server/CDN

Answer (score -1):

Say all of your SPA code are two files: `vendor.js` and `app.js`. To miss the cache when updated, typically what is done is compute hashes of the contents and put it in the file name: `vendor.<truncated  md5 hash>.js` and `app.<truncated md5 hash>.js`. Each time you build the project (assuming you changed at least one line) it gets a new hash, therefore a new filename, and miss the cache.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question states: "If the service is deployed, it will continue to load the cached js value unless REFRESHED. How do I fix this?" Your answer expects a refresh and then yes, the hashing format of the JS should work. BUT, the question is how is the cache refreshed WITHOUT a refresh?